# List index out of range error during processing the long string SQL field

Tags: python, sql, xml, pyodbc

Long story short - I created a terminal emulator in Python designed for interacting with MS SQL database. I've just implemented a SQL-XML conversion mechanism which allows user for exporting selected table into the pre-formatted XML file, however when I try to process data from **AdventureWorks2012->HumanResources.Department** table, containing very long strings, I'm receiving `List index out of range` error - this doesn't apply to smaller, more-humane fields in custom database.

Link to repo: https://github.com/jsarnowski96/pysql-console

How it works with small, custom tables:

[image]

How it works with **AdventureWorks2012** database:
[image]
[image]

Contents of **HumanResources.Department** table:
[image]

Suspected piece of code:

```
with open(finalPath, "w+", newline='') as xmlFile:
            xmlFile.write("<?xml version='1.0' ?>\n")
            xmlFile.write("<%s>\n" % table)
            for row in rows:
                 xmlFile.write("\t<field>\n")
                 indent_count += 1
                 for j in range(len(row)):
                     xmlFile.write("\t" * indent_count + "<%s>\n" % str(columns[j]))
                     xmlFile.write("\t" * (indent_count + 1) + "%s\n" % str(row[j]))
                     xmlFile.write("\t" * indent_count)
                     xmlFile.write("</%s>\n" % str(columns[j]))
                 indent_count = 1
                 xmlFile.write("\t</field>\n")
            xmlFile.write("</%s>\n" % table)
            print("SQL-XML conversion task finished successfully. File",fileName,"has been created.\n")
```

EDIT: after wrapping everything inside top-layer for loop with `columns` iterator, the error disappears, however it doesn't save any row into the destination file:

[image]

Modified part:

```
for i in range(len(columns)):
     for row in rows:
          xmlFile.write("\t<field>\n")
          indent_count += 1
          iterator = i
          for j in range(len(row)):
               xmlFile.write("\t" * indent_count + "<%s>\n" % str(columns[iterator]))
               xmlFile.write("\t" * (indent_count + 1) + "%s\n" % str(row[j]))
               xmlFile.write("\t" * indent_count)
               xmlFile.write("</%s>\n" % str(columns[iterator]))
               iterator += 1
          indent_count = 1
          xmlFile.write("\t</field>\n")
```

To me it looks like in the above case the program doesn't even execute the second `for` loop, thus no `<field>` tag appears in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code in GitHub, I think the problem might be that you're not actually filling the `columns` array correctly, leaving it empty. This would explain the out-of-range errors.

I loaded the AdventureWorks2012 db into my own SQL Server and ran the original `columnsQuery` SQL from your code:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'HumanResources.Department'
```

and this gave no results for the column names:

[image]

However, changing the query gave the correct column name results:

[image]

The full script I used was as follows (with some code copied from yours):

```
import pyodbc

dbConnection  = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=CPMLT5YHJMQ2;'
                      'Database=AdventureWorks2012;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

table = 'HumanResources.Department';

columnsQuery = list("SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('" + table + "')")
columnsQuery = ''.join(columnsQuery)

cursor = dbConnection .cursor()
cols = cursor.execute(columnsQuery).fetchall()
columns = list(str(c) for c in cols)
columns = list([c.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ','').replace("'",'').replace(',','').strip() for c in columns])

selectQuery = list("select * from " + table)
selectQuery = ''.join(selectQuery)
rows = cursor.execute(selectQuery).fetchall()

with open("test.xml", "w+", newline='') as xmlFile:
    xmlFile.write("<?xml version='1.0' ?>\n")
    xmlFile.write("<%s>\n" % table)
    indent_count = 1
    for row in rows:
        xmlFile.write("\t<field>\n")
        indent_count += 1
        for j in range(len(row)):
            xmlFile.write("\t" * indent_count + "<%s>\n" % str(columns[j]))
            xmlFile.write("\t" * (indent_count + 1) + "%s\n" % str(row[j]))
            xmlFile.write("\t" * indent_count)
            xmlFile.write("</%s>\n" % str(columns[j]))
        xmlFile.write("\t</field>\n")
        indent_count = 1
    xmlFile.write("</%s>\n" % table)
    xmlFile.close()
```

This produces an xml file like:

[image]

I hope this gives you something to work from.